# Change the file name in vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro through recording that will vlookup the dept code with the current worksheet name. 
I need help finding a way to change the file name to the current active sheet.
I am new so please be patient with me.

```
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Range("K9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-10],'S:\ Accounting\Inventory\2018 Inv\Physical Inventory\Year End\PIVR Adjustments\[October 2018 PIVR Adjustment Form 9418.xlsx]Pivot'!C1:C2,2,FALSE),0)"
    Range("K9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K9:K71").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Range("K9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-10],'S:\ Accounting\Inventory\2018 Inv\Physical Inventory\Year End\PIVR Adjustments\[October 2018 PIVR Adjustment Form 9996.xlsx]Pivot'!C1:C2,2,FALSE),0)"
    Range("K9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K9:K71").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: The code can be improved alot but As you mentioned are new to VBA, it would be helpful for you to learn yourself and improve it. To use active sheet as the file name, assuming you have a file named after the sheet at the same location you can use ActiveSheet.Name ` "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-10],'"S:\ Accounting\Inventory\2018 Inv\Physical Inventory\Year End\PIVR Adjustments\[" & ActiveSheet.Name& ".xlsx]Pivot'!C1:C2,2,FALSE),0)"`

Comment: @cyboashu - Could even go a step further and do a `Workbook` variable to shorten that bit up too

Comment: thanks @cyboashu , eaxctly what i was looking for!